# Listenening to GPS updates events without a reference to the Activity (in-background)

Tags: android, gps, xamarin.android

I have an application that needs to be aware of `GPS` updates on a regular bases. I am using `MonoForAndroid`, and thus
I have lots of code that I inherited from Windows and I still share this code with Windows and iOS.

In the current solution architecture, the Hardware related elements are separated in a different layer (`HAL Hardware Abstraction Layer`) which is at the bottom of the app heirachy.

I would like to keep the same architecture so that I do not need to change much of the ported code.

I followed the example on MonoForAndroid (receipe) http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

However, this assumes that the `Activity` is the `Listener`.

Questions:

1. How can I implement the `ILocationListener` without an `Activity`. I found that `ILocationListener` has a `Dispose()` method and a `Handle` field that I need to implement!! 
   When I try just creating a class that implements `ILocationListener` and pass it to `LocationManager.RequestLocationUpdates()` I get `InvalidArgumentException`. I am assuming that my implementation of `ILocationListener` is not valid.
2. Even when I make the `Activity` implements the `listener`, I get `SystemRunTimeException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

> First:

The class that implements `ILocationListener` needs to inhiret from `Java.Lang.Object` rather than from `System.Object`
This is because the `LocationListener` needs to exist in both `Java Delvik` and the `.NET` env. I got this tip from http://johnclaytonmoore.com/blog/monodroid-gps-listening
Once you inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`, you do not need to implement the `Handle` property and the `Dispose()` method

> Second:

The `SystemRunTimeException` was being thrown because Android expects the set up to happen on the the `MainLooper` thread. 
I used the `Applicatoin.Context` to do that without a need to reference the `Activity` as follows:

```
var handler = new Handler(Application.Context.MainLooper);
handler.Post(SetupLocationUpdatesListener);

private void SetupLocationUpdatesListener()
{
    _AndroidLocationUpdatesReceiver = new AndroidLocationListener();
    _LocationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, GpsFilters.MinimumGpsUpdatesTimeIntervalInMiliSeconds, GpsFilters.DistanceInMeters, _AndroidLocationUpdatesReceiver);
    _LocationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, GpsFilters.MinimumGpsUpdatesTimeIntervalInMiliSeconds, GpsFilters.DistanceInMeters, _AndroidLocationUpdatesReceiver);
    HookGpsEvents();
}
```

If you are interested in the full code of the LocationListener I have posted the whole thing on my blog, here is a link

http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/listenening-to-gps-updates-events-without-a-reference-to-the-activity-in-background-on-monoforandroid/